# Combine function signatures into overload

Tags: typescript

From a type like this:

```js
type Def = {
  m1(a1: A1, b1: B1): R1
  m2(a2: A2): R2
  m3(a3: A3, b3: B3, c3: C3): R3
}
```

I would like to compute a type like this:

```js
type F =
  ((name: 'm1', a1: A1, b1: B1) => R1) &
  ((name: 'm2', a2: A2) => R2) &
  ((name: 'm2', a3: A3, b3: B3, c3: C3) => R3)
```

that is the overloaded function type for a dispatcher method that would be dynamically generated.

I have managed to add the `name` parameter, i.e.:

```js
type H = {
  m1: (name: 'm1', a1: A1, b1: B1) => R1,
  m2: (name: 'm2', a2: A2) => R2,
  m3: (name: 'm3', a3: A3, b3: B3, c3: C3) => R3,
}
```

through simple object mapping and the `Parameter` and `ReturnType` helpers, but all my attempt at merging this into a single call signature have failed.

(see [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggjFAvFA3lAhgLinAvgKFElgCYlUNsSCjoYBmctLKegw8aAIQWTQCNseDsS5k+UQVGojujCVLb5ZUAMK8KAYyE1Oa8Vqq7iq+YdbtaUAEoa0AJx0rrBh0edm3F5VYAiEADMmfCgoAFs4AAp0OGx4ABpJWKgeAEpsWxDwkmiSOJJ0mxIssPpo+jj6RP4KlKqoTVrTQut6fHYAeg6oKwAxJHwu0KhIyIA7dDCIbAByCJnEmLi4auS0pAA+GzhUqAAyQe7Q0Ymp2bCSBYw80l3ELZddg6Hj8cnpqDnLxdqGatquPVGthmpsbPRUvggA))

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYKQEN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes sorry I tried to write an abstract example. The method does work, it is basically uses contravariance of function arguments to transform an `|` into an `&` right? I think I tried a similar intersection trick before using some other answer in StackOverflow but it just computed either `any` or `never`.

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
type IntersectMethods<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ?
    (x: ((name: K, ...args: A) => R)) => void :
    never
} extends Record<string, (x: infer I) => void> ? I : never
```

This uses [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) and infers [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) instead of [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) because the type to infer has been moved to a contravariant position (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for more about variance).  It's essentially the same technique as in [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218) with the wrinkle that we are finding only the methods and prepending a `name` parameter to each one.

Let's test it out:

```
type Def = {
  m1(a1: A1, b1: B1): R1
  m2(a2: A2): R2
  m3(a3: A3, b3: B3, c3: C3): R3
}

type F = IntersectMethods<Def>
/* type F = 
     ((name: "m1", a1: A1, b1: B1) => R1) & 
     ((name: "m2", a2: A2) => R2) & 
     ((name: "m3", a3: A3, b3: B3, c3: C3) => R3)
*/
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgOxFATgZygYxAWSiACwHsATNAHgBUA+GAXhgG9gZWYBtAaRgEsEYA1lDBEAZjEoBdAFwSukmFAAeyBGRgAKAHQ6AhigDmaWX1GoYAQQCU9WqfMAlGAH4WbDUtkaNCXQFsoWU4AGhgdLX0jWWtbGAcrGzpaADciHhIYaTdWBChk1GAAX0UVKDU0OKwiFBJyNBAUPgNQjxMEMxR4RJS0klpneEyYXPyUYFBIWAsARnomGF1ZacKJ6EsAJjnGBdl1lfA1iwBmLZ2YI5XV2AAhWYZtgCMl-cmYa837mCeYPau3k8+3wu4wOsAAwnd5phnn8wR8obsXmswQCEedLqC4pDtigYZiHPCcYi-g5UUT0SDXgARKDie5uPzTDS6abRaahB6st7TKyyBzTBnrZnraLrXlxdYMo7Mo7RI4c2X-UKYRUo8WktyLGD1RoIAwwAD0Bpg5AAtKaYH5dEJtQBXFCwQg8CoGfAVHgGBDVKAkIqUtYAMTmiGQ6CwuHwxDI5BpomowANACoYJigwxsqxvL4ArIAESM3OhFlsjlc27dLE2ABkMAzmh8-kCMHz60LCxFGwrBOrtbYmYbOebfiObd0iuOCtk13lMBVsjVsVJVmAiYN4yAA)